# Facebook SDK to manage facebook page

Tags: facebook, facebook-page, facebook-sdk-3.0

Is it possible to use the facebook sdk to manage a facebook group/page, without creating a facebook app (e.g. sort posts with most likes / comments etc.) ?

I've been looking through the SDK and in order to utilize the SDK for login etc. we would need to create a facebook app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you'll need to create a Facebook App. Doing so creates an App ID which allows you to further extend your possibilities (images, timeline, etc...)

The SDK will not function properly unless you are utilizing a proper (unique) Facebook App ID.